# Converting while loops into for loops

Tags: python, loops

> Convert the following while loop into a for loop. Your code should be written so that the return statement does not need to be altered. You are allowed to change the code before the while loop proper. string_list is a list of string that contains at least 15 instances of the string `'***'`

```
j=0 
while i<15: 
  if string_list[j] ='***': 
    i +=1 
  j +=1 
return j
```

I tried doing this first it says while `i<15` and `i = i+1` so i know i ranges from (0...15) not including 15 so basically we will have like `i = range(15)` so we will have something like:

```
for i in range(15):
```

I don't know what that `j` is doing there.

Comment: hint:  I doesn't always increase, the for loop doesn't go around 15 times, it could loop many more times than that

Comment: Code formatting is completely off and can make little out of it without that.

Comment: @pedantic, the homework tag is optional, not required. See [We won't do your homework for you], where it specifically says it's the poster's choice (and gives advice about how to post homework questions).

Comment: @Hamza see Keith's answer - you're not likely to get a more heplpful hint than that. Think about when `i` increments and think about when `j` increments. They're not the same.

Comment: should give an error since i starts undefined.

Comment: We don't really know for sure when `j` increments because the indentation is wrong

Comment: `if string_list[j] ='***':` will give an error. You must mean `== '***':`.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you meant to write `string_list[j] == '***'` instead of `string_list[j] ='***'`.  I will also assume `i` is initialised to `0`.

```
i, j = 0, 0 
while i < 15: 
  if string_list[j] == '***': 
    i += 1 
  j += 1 
return j
```

The first step is to understand what the loop is actually doing.  It is iterating through `string_list` elements, and every time an `'***'` is encountered, `i` is incremented.  The loop will terminate when `i` reaches `15`, and since a precondition was given that `string_list` contains at least 15 copies of `'***'` we do expect the loop should terminate.

When the loop terminates, `i` will be equal to `15` and `j` will simply have counted the number of elements in the list up until this point.

So to start you off, you could try iterating like this:

```
for s in string_list:
  if s == `***`:
    # keep track of how many times this has happened
    # break if you've seen it happen 15 times
  j += 1
return j
```

Answer (score 2):

```
j = [i for i,x in enumerate(string_list) if x=='***'][15]
return j
```

lazy version inspired by comments from Peter and astynax

```
from itertools import islice
j = next(islice((i for i,x in enumerate(string_list) if x=='***'), 15, None))
return j
```

Comment: A lazy version: `j = next(j for count, j in enumerate(i for i, x in enumerate(string_list) if x == '***') if j == 15)`

Comment: i dont know why you guys are so uptight when someone else answers, that is the only reason i am posting this question because i do not know how to approach or write this problem,

Comment: Lazy variant `j = list(itertools.islice((i for i,x in enumerate(string_list) if x=='***'), 15, 15 + 1))`

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why the list comprehension version has a [15] at the end? It looks like the terminating condition, but I've never seen list comprehension written that way. I tried testing it but got index error (out of range).

Comment: @Shaken_not_stirred, the `[15]` is not part of the list comprehension, it's just taking the 16th item from the list. If you run just the LC without the `[15]`, you'll see that you've got a list with less than 16 items, so you get an index error.