# change while to for

Tags: python, python-3.6

This is the a function using while loop

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(input_list):
        if input_list[index] < 0:
            count = count + 1
        index = index + 1
    return count
```

Can someone tell me how to use for loop to construct this function ?

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0
    for i in range (input_list[]):
        if i<0 :
            count += 1;
        else:
            count += 0;
    return count
```

It always give 0 when I input any list.

Comment: Can you give an exemple of you input list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting while loops into for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200077/converting-while-loops-into-for-loops)

Comment: what is `count += 0` supposed to do? BTW you should remove the semicolons

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using list comprehension for this:

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    return sum(1 for i in input_list if i<0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0
    for i in input_list:
        if i<0 :
            count += 1
    print count
    return count

input_list = [1,-2,-6,4,5,9, -3, 8,-88]
count_negative(input_list)
```

**Output :**
4

Answer (score 0):

range needs the length of the list instead of input_list[]

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0
    for i in range (len(input_list)):
        if input_list[i]<0 :
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `range()` and `len()` in a `for` loop is a poor way of iterating through a list because you have to maintain the iterator yourself.  Sometimes it is justified, but not here.  You don't need the index, you get an iterator for free:

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0

    for item in input_list:
        if item < 0 :
            count += 1 
        else:                       
            count += 0

    return count
```

As someone else said, the `count += 0` is useless, but there is a case (a weak one) for saying it is a documentary place holder, so I left it in.  I did remove the trailing semi-colons though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_negative(input_list):
    count = 0
    for i in input_list:
        if i<0 :
            count += 1;
        else:
            count += 0;
    return count
```

Try this one it will give correct answer. now i will be the each element of list.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm